# copy paste of tab delimited text results in strange formatting in Excel?

Tags: excel

My source file is a tab delimited text file (*.txt). I am copy pasting from the *.txt to a blank *.xlsx workbook. I have Microsoft Office Excel 2010 installed on my computer. I have notepad++ installed on my computer.

The tab delimited text files are normal text files using "\t" tab characters to separate numeric values in to columns. Example:

```
0   0   0.5528369
0   1   0.0
1   0   0.1230636
1   1   0.0
1   0   0.2113225
1   1   0.0
3   0   0.0752651
3   1   0.0
```

Using the same example, here is a screen shot showing the characters in the source file:

[image]

Issue #1: after copy pasting from text file to worksheet, excel removes tabs, squishing each row of text together, for example:

[image]

As a workaround, I use a text-replace function in Notepad++ to replace each tab in the source text with a comma. This operation results in something that looks like this:

```
0,  0,  0.5528369
0,  1,  0.0
1,  0,  0.1230636
1,  1,  0.0
1,  0,  0.2113225
1,  1,  0.0
3,  0,  0.0752651
3,  1,  0.0
```

After copy/pasting in to excel this version with commas, I am now able to perform the excel function Data->Text-to-columns. However, there are issues with this, too.

Issue #2: Text copy pasted in to excel is not treated as a number. Switching the type of the data from General to Number does not work. It remains as text. On closer inspection, it appears that Excel added white space to the end of each number, and this prohibits it from recognizing it as a number. For example:

[image]

Currently I am having to hand edit each cell in excel to remove the extra white space, which enables me to set the type to Number.

Both of these issues stem from performing trivial copy paste operations and I am at a loss to understand why they are occurring or how to resolve them in a straightforward manner. I would like to copy paste in to excel as described above without having either issue occur.

Comment: Can you check in Notepad++ whether you have the trailing spaces? I normally copy-paste tab-delimited data into Excel with no issues... What regional settings do you have too?

Comment: @pnuts: the source file also has many other rows of data that are not tab delimited, and importing the the file using Get External Data results in me having to perform a cleanup operation to remove the extra rows. Not an ideal solution because of the manual labor involved.

Comment: @captain: there are no trailing spaces. I edited my OP with a screen shot showing the hidden characters, including the tabs. You can see that each row is terminated with the carriage return and line feed, but no spaces (a space would appear as a little orange dot, a feature of notepad++'s "show all character's" function)

Comment: Is this a new, "clean" excel file you are pasting in to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution fixes both issues.

Although the text is squished together, as shown in the OP, the tab characters are still in the string. With that said, the solution is to:

1) copy paste into cell A1 (the text will appear squished together)

2) select column A

3) select Data->Text-to-columns and in the dialog window select tab delimited formatting

4) click Finish

5) select data in columns A->C and change type from General to Number.

It is not at all obvious why Excel is designed to squish the text together. This gives the misleading impression that the tab characters have been stripped away. However, the tab characters are there. Further, after applying text-to-columns, the values in each cell can now be converted from General to Number type without issue (there is no white space added to the end).

Comment: I found that if I paste the data into notepad++, then re-copy the data from notepad++ and paste in excel, I get the expected behavior of data into multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

### This solutions avoids having to use text-to-columns

I was having the same issue. I was outputting data to the browser inside of `<pre>` tags.  I am also using `\t` between columns of data. When I paste into excel, everything goes into one column.

I paste the data into notepad++ to make sure that tabs were between all columns, and sure enough they were! ***I then copied the data from notepad++ and pasted it into excel, and it worked as expected!***

### Note: you can use regular notepad and get the same effect

---

***An even better solution***, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46788719/692331), is that you can output your data into a `<textarea>`, then copy from that. The reason that works is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46646963/692331), along with an explaination of what's actually going on.