# Copy hyperlink text and plain text to the clipboard, then paste them into Excel using Javascript/JQuery in multiple cells of a row?

Tags: javascript, excel, text, hyperlink, clipboard

My goal is to make a function that, on a specific page, collects **data** and copies it to the clipboard, later pasted into a Google Sheet or Excel Spreadsheet.

The **data** appears in different places on a web-page and is presented as follows:

```html
<!-- Somewhere throughout the web page -->
<div data-cy="a">
  <strong><a href="www.example.com">text</a></strong>
</div>

<!-- Another place throughout the web page -->
<div data-cy="b">
  <strong>another text</strong>
</div>
```

Moreover, I need to push some of my simple strings, such as `var text = 'different text'`.

In an Excel spreadsheet, the three values should be pasted in three matching fields in one row:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [text](https://www.example.com) | another text | different text |

Here is my code so far:

```js
 var a = $('*[data-cy="a"]').html().replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('<strong>','').replaceAll('</strong>','') // extract 'a'.
 var b = $('*[data-cy="b"]').html().replaceAll('\n','').split(/[><]/)[2]; // extract 'b'.
 var c = 'different text';
 
 var allCells = a + '\t' + b + '\t' + c; // using Tab character to divide between cells.

function copyToClipboard(str) {
    
    function listener(e) {
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", str);
        e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
};
 
copyToClipboard(allCells);
```

I tried both the deprecated and more recent versions of `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`, but none of these seem to give me the option to paste the values in different cells in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645125/tab-delimited-text-copy-paste-to-excel/46646963#46646963) helped me to figure out what is actually happening.
In order to *work around this*, unfortunately, I created a new table in the DOM and copied the elements from there. Pasting into the Excel sheet works like a charm.

```js
// Extraction of variables
var a = $('*[data-cy="a"]').html().replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('<strong>','').replaceAll('</strong>','') // extract 'a'.
var b = $('*[data-cy="b"]').html().replaceAll('\n','').split(/[><]/)[2]; // extract 'b'.
var c = 'different text';

let allCells = [$(clientName), locationCompany, treatedBy];

// Table creation
var table = $('<table>').addClass('table').attr('id', 'excel-data');
var row = $('<tr>');

for(i=0; i<allCells.length; i++) {
    row.append($('<td>').html(allCells[i]));
}
table.append(row);

$('[data="element-data"]').append(table);
```

```js
// Select & copy table function
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        document.execCommand("copy");

    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
        range.execCommand("Copy");
    }
}
```