# Skewed order of magnitude when copying text from tab-separated text to Excel

Tags: excel, text

I have the following data points formatted as follows in a tab-separated text file:

```
7.23e-10    0.125   9.0375e-11
4.946739999999999e-07   0.16666666666666666 8.244566666666665e-08
```

When I manually copy these data to Excel however, it seems like the order of magnitude is skewed in some, but not all of the cases, namely:

```
7.23E-10    0.125   9.04E-07
4.95E+08    0.166666667 8.24E+07
```

I tried looking for a reason and solution e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645125/tab-delimited-text-copy-paste-to-excel), but didn't manage to find anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Import the file using Power Query, and set the data type of the columns **by locale** according to the separators used in the Text File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the settings regarding the separators for decimal and thousands.

I changed these in Excel in options>advanced to . and empty, respectively (e.g. 1.000,01 would be represented as 1000.01).

However, Excel does not allow an empty separator for thousands, so **silently** added back in . for the thousand separator.

As a result, both the decimal and thousands separator were now . (periods).

This caused the unexpected behavior as described in the question.

The remedy is to change these separators in the regional settings of your Windows machine and have Excel use the system settings, instead of changing these separators directly in the Excel settings.